# Does namespaces provide any isolation and relation with the context

Tags: kubernetes

I am new in Kubernetes and I am trying to understand the concept of namespaces and context.
It is basically allows to group resources into logical sets.
An a context is the combination of user/cluster/namespace.
What I am not sure is if namespaces provide any kind of isolation.
E.g. if we have a user A that uses cluster C1 and namespace foo and user B that uses cluster C1 as well and the namespace foo, does any changes that user A does affect user B?
E.g. if user A starts deleting pods would that be also visible by user B?

Comment: If a user has permissions to delete pods in a namespace, then of course those changes will be visible to other users who have access to the same namespace. It's like two people sharing the same directory on your filesystem. If you want isolation between users; **use different namespaces** (and an appropriate access control configuration).

Comment: @larsks: So basically the namespace is a logical grouping only and is like a shared view among users right?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer that question. A namespace is a a box full of things, and if you have given multiple people access to that box they will see the same things.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am not sure is if namespaces provide any kind of isolation.
> E.g. if we have a user A that uses cluster C1 and namespace foo and
> user B that uses cluster C1

Namespaces are for grouping resources. To control access to the C1 cluster by namespace, then it's doable via [creating `Roles`, and `RoleBindings` for the users and issuing certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#normal-user) that restrict access to a given namespace. It does not mean user A deployed pod cannot be accessed in runtime via a network call initiated from a pod deployed by user B in his bar namespace. For that network isolation, you need to use k8s `NetworkPolicies`.

> as well and the namespace foo, does any changes that user A does
> affect user B? E.g. if user A starts deleting pods would that be also
> visible by user B?

Yes, it is visible. It's just the same cluster two users have access to the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, namespaces provides a mechanism for isolating groups of resources within a single cluster. Names of resources need to be unique within a namespace, but not across namespaces.

Here are a few important concepts to keep in mind when working with namespaces:

Resources inside namespaces are logically separated from each other but they can still communicate
Namespaces dont provide true multi-tenancy the way other solutions do ( such as public cloud virtual infrastructure or Openstack Private Cloud )
There is a single default Kubernetes namespace, but you can create as many namespaces as needed within a cluster
Namespaces cannot be nested within each other.